# i want to get data in the subscribe code for recyclerview

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

**MainViewModel**

```
var userList = mutableListOf<UserDataClass>()
fun getUser(){
        disposable +=
            userService
                .getUserData()
                .subscribeOn(io())
                .observeOn(mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        userList.add(it)
                        Log.d("get userList" , userList.toString())},
                    {Log.d("error" , it.toString())}
                )
    }
```

**Activity**

```
val retrofit = HttpBuilder.retrofit.create(UserService::class.java)
        val mainViewModel = MainViewModel(retrofit)
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var userList = mutableListOf<UserDataClass>(UserDataClass("1" , "1" , "1"))

        val rv_board = binding.rvBoard
        val boardAdapter = BoardAdapter(userList)
        rv_board.adapter = boardAdapter
        rv_board.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        boardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            mainViewModel.getUser()
            userList = mainViewModel.userList //userList = []
            BoardAdapter(userList)
            boardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Log.d("userList" , userList.toString())
        }
```

in my `ViewModel`, I create `userList` and add it(`userDataClass`). it works well. but when I call `mainViewModel.userList`, `it = []`. I don't know why `mainViewModel.userList` reset.

How can I bring my `userList` or `userDataClass` getting by `retrofit`?
and how can I run my `RecyclerView`?

Comment: The API call hasn't completed yet when you get your userList.  GetUsers is non blocking, next line won't wait for its completion in another thread.  Make your VM's userList a LiveData and observe its change in the activity.